# Android with phonegap. How to access web view from JAVA classes?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to run specific javascript on certain scenarios.  I would like not to need a plugin, as plugins rely on having the application open.

My idea is to be able to open a notification while the app is closed (I have this this working), and have the notification open the app if closed or bring it to front if app is open.

So the above is already the way it works...

With this said, however, I want to be able to have the notification pass some javascript to the web view. I want to open links based on the notification that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loadUrl` method to pass javascript to the page like this:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload = function(){alert(\"haha\");};");
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to reference the phonegap webview from outside the main activity class.

Comment: Create a method in your activity to manipulate webview from outside.

Comment: How are you opening your activity? If you're using intents you could pass any additional info with the intent as a Bundle object.

Comment: Its the main activity, and it runs as singleTop.  So it does not rerun if its already open as it should, so the intent method may not work. 
I like the method idea. How would I do that in a main activity. Like how would I access it from somewhere else.

Comment: Intent would work if you'd overridden the onNewIntent method in your singleTop activity.

Comment: Hey man, the suggestion to use onNewIntent was perfect.  Opened me to a world of possibilities. Thanks. Where can I find other framework/predefined methods for activities?

Comment: In the official android api documentation.